# WebApi and relational data

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I've generated a WebApi in visualstudio to use in an angular frontend. It is used to store and serve data about meetings. Each meeting can have one or more agenda points. For now the HTTP GET gives me JSON like:

```
[
    {
        "Agendapunten": [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "Omschrijving": "Omschrijving 1",
                "VolgNr": 2,
                "VergaderingenId": 1
            },
            {
                "Id": 3,
                "Omschrijving": "Omschrijving 2",
                "VolgNr": 1,
                "VergaderingenId": 1
            }
        ],
        "Id": 1,
        "Datum": "2014-02-05T00:00:00",
        "Status": 5
    },
    {
        "Agendapunten": [
            {
                "Id": 11,
                "Omschrijving": "Omschrijving 3",
                "VolgNr": 4,
                "VergaderingenId": 20
            }
        ],
        "Id": 20,
        "Datum": "2014-02-05T00:00:00",
        "Status": 5
    }
]
```

When i add meetings with POST or update Meeting fields with PUT everything works just fine.  As a WebApi/JSON newby i was expecting to update agendapoints (agendapunten in dutch) in pretty much the same fashion: just put in a new value somewhere in the above mention JSON structure and send it to the WebApi... After sending this request nothing changes in the database.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm suspecting that i have to build a separate WebApi to retrieve and update agendapoints. Or do something with a different calling approach like

```
http://webserveraddress/api/meeting/1/agendapoints (GET)
Http://webserveraddress/api/meeting/1/agendapoints/1 { new values} (PUT)
```

I hope my question is clear, despite my poor english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: No, you do not have to define a separate API service just for agendas. You can interact with it through the meeting resource:

e.g. The *api/meetings/{id}* service would take your meeting object (including agendas) and save the meeting, but also take care of finding out which agendas are no longer in the object, thus deleting them from the db, which ones are new, thus adding them, and which ones were changed, thus updating them. E.g.

```
//api/meetings/{id} - PUT
public HttpResponse Update(int id, Meeting meeting)
{
  db.update(id, meeting);
  foreach (var agenda in meeting.agendas)
  {
    if (db.exists(agenda))
    {
      agenda.update()
    } 
    else
    {
      agenda.insert()
    }
    //also take care of deleting agendas no longer there
  }
}
```

Some people might argue against this approach and suggest defining a separate resource Url; others might agree and say that agendas at it's core is really just an extension of a meeting, which means if an agenda changes, the meeting changes.

To have agendas as a separate resource, you would define a brand new Agendas controller which would interact with agendas on the *api/agendas/{id}* url. E.g.

```
public class AgendasController
{
  //api/agendas/{agendaId} - PUT
  public HttpResponse Update(int agendaId, Agenda agenda)
  {
    db.update(agendaId, agenda);
  }
}
```

You might also want to have the agenda methods on your MeetingsController and define your route as *api/meetings/{meetingId}/agendas/{agendaId}* - like you have at the bottom of your question. The routes might be a bit tricky to define if you're using convention-based routing. In Web API 2 you can use attribute routing which will simplify this kind of routing.

See this article for details on attribute routing: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Thanks, for practical reasons i've decided to use the seperate webapi approach. I've created a resource to get,post, put and delete single agendas. Thanks for help me find the right direction!